# How to scroll diagonally with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Are there projects or plugins that utilize javascript or jQuery to scroll diagonally?

e.g. when you scroll down your content, It would be pulled at the top-left corner of the browser; and when you scroll up your content would be pulled at the bottom-right of the corner.

I see some similar project/website that they animate their elements when scroll. Most of the site that use javascript has some lags with the effect though. Another i've seen is using html5 + parallax effect similar to "Nike a Better World" (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/12/behind-the-scenes-of-nike-better-world/)

Can you point me where can be a good starting point? Basically I want to scroll the items diagonally left-or-right. If this can be done plainly in HTML5, I would highly consider that since I feel It would have less lag or less calculation being done.

[image]

Comment: scroll right and down...

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/K4YSq/ ?

Comment: cool.. exactly like that :) appreciate the jsfiddle. I'll be borrwoing this snippet.

Comment: @j08691 though it breaks when I put some content on the div.

Comment: @j08691, please post your code in an answer below so it can be accepted after you fix it for the OP.

Comment: _How_ does it break?  The only problem I see is that content overflows the `div`'s.  That can be easily solved with `overflow: hidden;`.   http://jsfiddle.net/K4YSq/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to create the effect that you wanted in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/t0nyh0/8QTYt/36/

**Important Tidbits**

1. A "fixed" full-width and full-height wrapper that holds all your moving elements help you animate the div more consistently based on the scroll position (which is effectively the "keyframe" number).
2. `scroll_max`, `wrapper_width`, and `wrapper_height` helps normalize the dimensions of wrapper. I.e. the very bottom of the scroll corresponds to the bottom/right of the wrapper, and the very top of the scroll corresponds with the top/left of the wrapper.
3. Set your body's height to whatever number of "keyframes" that you want.
4. To move from top left to bottom right on going down, adjust the `top` and `left` properties.  For the reverse, adjust the `bottom` and `right` properties.  Of course, you will need to formulate your own calculations for more complex animations, but know that doing `$window.scrollTop()` will give you the "keyframe" number.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="a">
        <h1>Meats</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <h1>Veggies</h1>
        <hr/>
        <p>Veggies sunt bona vobis, proinde vos postulo esse magis daikon epazote peanut chickpea bamboo shoot rutabaga maize radish broccoli rabe lotus root kohlrabi napa cabbage courgette mustard squash mung bean.</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    height: 1000px; // 1000 keyframes
}

#wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    border: 2px solid navy;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#a {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #daf1d7;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#b
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #d2d0ee;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

​

**Javscript**

```
var $window = $(window);
var $a = $('#a');
var $b = $('#b');

var scroll_max = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var wrapper_height = $('#wrapper').height();
var wrapper_width = $('#wrapper').width();

$window.scroll(function() {
    console.log(scroll_max);
    $a.css({
        'top': ($window.scrollTop() / scroll_max) * wrapper_height,
        'left': ($window.scrollTop() / scroll_max) * wrapper_width
    });
    $b.css({
        'bottom': ($window.scrollTop() / scroll_max) * wrapper_height,
        'right': ($window.scrollTop() / scroll_max) * wrapper_width
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution for you (**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/K4YSq/)**):

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    $('#a').css({
        'width': $(this).scrollTop(),
        'height': $(this).scrollTop()
    });
    $('#b').css({
        'width': 300-$(this).scrollTop(),
        'height': 300-$(this).scrollTop()
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#a,#b {
    position:fixed;
    background: orange;
}
#a{
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#b {
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
body {
 height:2000px;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```