# Diagonal Scroll Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got a issue here. Im trying to scroll diagonally my document. It takes the doc width and height and adds its values in each section element. I know how to scroll it in y angle, but cand find a way to make the x angle scroll synchronously scroll width the y angle.

Thanks for any tip!

Here's my js:

```
$(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var sectionsNumbers = $("#content section").length - 1;
    var sectionCount = 0;
    // Scroll sets
    var windowScrollX = ((sectionsNumbers + 1) * windowWidth) - windowWidth;
    alert(windowScrollX);
    // Set mask w and h
    $("#mask").css("width", windowWidth);
    $("#mask").css("height", windowHeight);
    $(".scrollRule").css("height", (sectionsNumbers + 1) * windowHeight);
    $("#content section").each(function() {
        // Defines its width and height
        $(this).css("width", windowWidth);
        $(this).css("height", windowHeight);
        // Defines its position
        $(this).css("left", sectionCount * windowWidth);
        $(this).css("top", sectionCount * windowHeight);
        sectionCount++;
    });
    // When window scrolls
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var curScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("#debug").html(curScrollTop);
        $("#content").css("top", "-" + curScrollTop);
    });
});​
```

**I GOT IT!**

I just have to divide the window total width by the window total scroll height. Thanks to all!

Comment: Could you post your html too? Or put this up on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: here's it: http://jsfiddle.net/7CpbV/

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689765/how-to-scroll-diagonally-with-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 2):

try using the animate function of jQuery. Just replace the integers of my code example with your calculated position values.

```
jQuery('html,body').animate(
    {
         scrollTop: 25
         ,scrollLeft: 20
    }
    ,'slow'
);
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: You did not understand my issue.